# How to skip first row and read upto five rows from csv in PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, fputcsv

How to skip first row and read upto five rows from csv in PHP

Hello,

I have following code in which I want to skip first row in csv that is headers of columns and read upto five rows of csv file.

Current code skip first row but display all records.

How can I achieve this ?

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

define('CSV_PATH', '/var/www/Products_upload_12499/'); // specify CSV file path

$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "skipfirstrow.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
$csvfile  = fopen($csv_file, 'r');

$counter = 1;
while ($data = fgetcsv($csvfile)) 
{
    if($counter==1) {
            $counter++;
            continue;
            }       }
    $days = trim($data[0]);
    echo "==>> " . $days."\n";
        if ($counter >= 6) {
        exit();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library

Comment: I work on Ubuntu so I dont think so Excel works in Ubuntu. Therefore I am using csv files

Comment: You wanted rows 2,3,4,5 correct?

Comment: @Nikita did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes skip first row and after that need 5 rows

Comment: Why there is two closing brackets  }      } after continue; ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `if else` conditional that only outputs the rows you want, and that breaks the `while` loop when you got all the rows you wanted:

```
$row = 0;
while ($data = fgetcsv($csvfile)) 
{
    $row++;//starts off with $row = 1
    if (($row>1)&&($row<6))//rows 2,3,4,5
    {
        foreach ($data as $cell)
        {
           echo "|  {$cell}  |";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
    else if ($row>=6)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can replace the `echo "|  {$cell}  |";` code with whatever you like the code to output.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

just skip first line by not equal assign `!=` ,let me know is it work

```
$counter = 1;
while ($data = fgetcsv($csvfile)) 
{
    if($counter !=1) {
      $days = trim($data[0]);
      echo "==>> " . $days."\n";
      if($counter >= 6)
        break;
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: oh yes Thanks @vp_art

Comment: Nice catch, @Nikita :) But unbalanced `{}` here now.

Comment: No its not unbalanced  .. All `{}` are properly closed

Comment: @Nikita, I fix that. see [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37404454/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another code to achieve this.
`fgets` used to skip lines to avoid excess csv parsing.

```
if (($f = fopen('test.csv', 'r')) === false)
  throw new Exception('File not found');

$skip = 1;
$length = 5;

for ($i = 1; $i < $skip; $i++) fgets($f); // skip first $skip lines
for ($i = $skip; $i < $skip + $length; $i++) {
  $row = fgetcsv($f);
  echo implode(', ', $row)."<br/>\n";
}
```